# About the existence of a convergent sequence

Tags: banach-spaces, convexity, limits-and-convergence

Let $(A_n)$ be a set sequence in a Banach space wheresuch that $A_n$ is nonempty, closed and convex for every $n=1,2\dots$. Assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{n,m\to \infty} d(A_n,A_m)=0$ where d is the Hausdorff distance between two sets.

My question is whether there exists a convergent sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $x_n\in A_n$ for every $n$?

I asked this question on MSE, but haven't got answers.

Comment: Here is link to math.SE question: [Existence of convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2344740).

Comment: Great question! Can it be shown that the answer is **no** if we weaken the assumptions to: 1) the base space $X$ is just a complete metric space, and 2) the sets $A_n$ are nonempty and closed (but not necessarily convex).

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: Is your comment a question or a statement? It begins like a question but it doesn't end with a question mark, so how should we understand it?

Answer (score 3):

[Fedor Petrov's](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4312/fedor-petrov) answer to my [more general question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273614/hausdorff-distance-and-cauchy-sequences) implies a positive answer to this question, as Banach spaces are complete metric spaces.